# Problema com result undefined - nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Estou tendo problema para recuperar os dados do db SQL Server com o node o mesmo não puxa de forma alguma o result da query informada:

module mssql

**dbConnectio**

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'id', 
        database: 'db_name',
        port: '1433',
        connectionTimeout: '5000',
        requestTimeout: '5000',
        options: {encrypt: true}
    };


var pool = function(){
    var conn =  new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err){
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}

module.exports = function(){
    return pool;
}
```

**FormulasDAO**

```js
function FormulasDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

FormulasDAO.prototype.getFormulas = function(callback){
    this._connection.query('select * from USUARIO', callback);
}


module.exports = function() {
    return FormulasDAO;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tag da pergunta ta incompleta. Eu entrei pensado que era node.js somente,mas era outra. -1. Muito confuso.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @MauryDeveloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
var pool = async function(){
    var conn = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config, async function(err){
        var request = await new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}
```

Se funcionar, faz o teste assim (talvez precisa de async/await somente na conexão)

```
var pool = function(){
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, async function(err){
        var request = await new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: fiz o teste e o primeiro me retorna o seguinte erro:   TypeError: this._connection.query is not a function

E o segundo código continua retornando 
undefined

Comment: Você já conseguiu se conectar e voltar as informações de alguma forma? Por que assim, seu problema provavelmente é do nodejs em relação a sincronidade. Quando eu comecei no Node apanhei muito sobre isso, e ainda apanho até hoje as vezes. Como se trata de um uso de uma lib 'mssql', é mais dificil alguém ajudar, só se alguém a utiliza também. O que eu aconselho é ao menos conseguir fazer a conexão e voltar as informações, mesmo que o código seja meio bagunçado e posteriormente fazer a divisão em funções menores.

Comment: Teste uma dessas duas formas: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait ou https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises. Após fazer funcionar, vai ser mais fácil dividir o código em funções menores, caso for necessário.

Comment: Apenas para explicar melhor, o nodejs trabalha de forma assincrona, ou seja, no meio de um script se você acessa algum arquivo ou conexão com internet, que exige um certo tempo para ser executado, ele continua o código. O que está acontecendo, portanto, é que o sql.Request embora chamado, tem um delay, e como ele não está esperando, ele já continua o código e mostra como undefined, termina a função e retornando undefined. O teste do await foi para isso, pra tentar faze-lo esperar, mas não deu certo. Teste algum dos códigos que citei que está na doc da lib, provavelmente dará certo.